# How to use elsarticle documentclass in two column?

Tags: two-column, elsarticle

I use elsarticle document class to format my paper. However, i went to display my paper in two column, used this:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

After compiling, I don't have the PDF, and i have this message

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.10.8)
```

Someone can help me please.

```
Copyright 2007, 2008, 2009 Elsevier Ltd
%% 
%% This file is part of the 'Elsarticle Bundle'.
%% ---------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'Elsarticle Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%% 

%% Template article for Elsevier's document class `elsarticle'
%% with numbered style bibliographic references
%% SP 2008/03/01

%%\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the option review to obtain double line spacing
%% \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
 \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
%% please give \usepackage{epsfig}

%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%% The amsthm package provides extended theorem environments
%% \usepackage{amsthm}

%% The lineno packages adds line numbers. Start line numbering with
%% \begin{linenumbers}, end it with \end{linenumbers}. Or switch it on
%% for the whole article with \linenumbers.
%% \usepackage{lineno}

\journal{Nuclear Physics B}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome please follow the link given in the comment above and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

I have no problem with the following code. Note that `twocolumn` should not be issued.

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}
\author{So Nia}
\address{Department, University}
\ead{so.nia@somewhere.xyz}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Start}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it don't work with me , please can you tell me which latex editor do you use me i used texmaker 4.5

Comment: @So.nia “It doesn't work” is too vague. Please, add to your question an example of the code you're trying to compile.

Comment: please can you tell me if you use MiKTex or TeXlive ? I use MiKTeX and the error is "!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file txsy): Font txsy at 480 not found"

Comment: @So.nia I have TeX Live

Comment: I supose the problem is with MiKTeX . have you ever encountered this error: "!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file txsy): Font txsy at 480 not found" with MiKteX

Comment: @So.nia You need to install the `txfonts` package.

Comment: i have the same problem "pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file txsy): Font txsy at 480 not found"

Comment: @So.nia Remove the `times` option

Answer (score 1):

Copyright 2007, 2008, 2009 Elsevier Ltd

```
%% 
%% This file is part of the 'Elsarticle Bundle'.
%% ---------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'Elsarticle Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%% 

%% Template article for Elsevier's document class `elsarticle'
%% with numbered style bibliographic references
%% SP 2008/03/01

%%\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the option review to obtain double line spacing
%% \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
 \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

%% For including figures, graphicx.sty has been loaded in
%% elsarticle.cls. If you prefer to use the old commands
%% please give \usepackage{epsfig}

%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%% The amsthm package provides extended theorem environments
%% \usepackage{amsthm}

%% The lineno packages adds line numbers. Start line numbering with
%% \begin{linenumbers}, end it with \end{linenumbers}. Or switch it on
%% for the whole article with \linenumbers.
%% \usepackage{lineno}

\journal{Nuclear Physics B}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Added content to original question by editing.