# How can I use subtable as single column inside twocolumn documentclass?

Tags: tables, two-column, cuted

I have following base `\twocolumn` setup taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307286/127048, here I want to put a side-by-side tables using `subtable` as its in single column:

```tex
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}

\end{document}
```

Is it possible to apply following solution [Table side by side cannot run](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/541525/127048) as it is applied to a single column. I have tried to put @Zarko's solution inside the  `\twocolumn[{ ... }]` block but I have face with following error: `LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

Tried approach:

```tex
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
\twocolumn[
{
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \footnotesize
        \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
        \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
              \hline
              \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}}   & \textbf{Notes}   \\
              \hline
              h               & \SI{10668}{m}      & Altitude         \\
              $\rho$          & \SI{0.379}{kg/m^3} & Air density      \\
              Ma              & 0.90               & Mach number      \\
              $\theta = 0$
                              & \SI{2.86}{\degree} & Initial attitude \\
              \hline
            \end{tabular*}
            \caption{Flight conditions}
        \end{subtable}
        \hfill
        \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
              \hline
              \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}} & \textbf{Notes}  \\
              \hline
              A               & \SI{18.22}{m^2}  & Wing area       \\
              b               & \SI{0.379}{m}    & Wing span       \\
              c               & \SI{2.91}{m}     & Wing mean chord \\
              AR              & 2.45             & Aspect ratio    \\
              e               & 0.92             & Oswald factor   \\
              \hline
            \end{tabular*}
            \caption{Geometric data}
        \end{subtable}
    \end{table}
}]
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove `\twocolumn[{` the two tables will fit side by side in a single column of the two column document. It is this what you want?

Comment: No sorry if I did not make it clear. I want to make it fit into the two column instead of single column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, your question is not entirely clear what you after. If  you like to have float `table` at bottom of the page (if there is sufficient space for it after the point of its insertion), than you see, if the package `stfloats` gives what you after:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}
\section{Start}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table*}[b]
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
  \hline
  \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}}   & \textbf{Notes}   \\
  \hline
  h               & \SI{10668}{m}      & Altitude         \\
  $\rho$          & \SI{0.379}{kg/m^3} & Air density      \\
  Ma              & 0.90               & Mach number      \\
  $\theta = 0$
                  & \SI{2.86}{\degree} & Initial attitude \\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Flight conditions}
\end{subtable}
\hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
  \hline
  \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}} & \textbf{Notes}  \\
  \hline
  A               & \SI{18.22}{m^2}  & Wing area       \\
  b               & \SI{0.379}{m}    & Wing span       \\
  c               & \SI{2.91}{m}     & Wing mean chord \\
  AR              & 2.45             & Aspect ratio    \\
  e               & 0.92             & Oswald factor   \\
  \hline
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Geometric data}
\end{subtable}
    \end{table*}

\lipsum[2-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make the two tables span two columns, you can use the package `cuted` with `\begin{strip}` ... `\end{strip}`.

For these two tables to fit `\footnotesize` is not necessary.

The tabulars are inside a `minipage`, so they are not floats, then it is necessary to use `\captionof{table}{<text>}` instead of `\caption`.

`\begin{minipage}[b] ..`  aligns the two captions.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{cuted}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
\section{Start}

1.      \lipsum[1-2] (END)

\begin{strip} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<

    \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
            \hline
            \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}}   & \textbf{Notes}   \\
            \hline
            h               & \SI{10668}{m}      & Altitude         \\
            $\rho$          & \SI{0.379}{kg/m^3} & Air density      \\
            Ma              & 0.90               & Mach number      \\
            $\theta = 0$
            & \SI{2.86}{\degree} & Initial attitude \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular*}
    \captionof{table}{Flight conditions}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lll}
            \hline
            \textbf{Symbol} & {\textbf{Value}} & \textbf{Notes}  \\
            \hline
            A               & \SI{18.22}{m^2}  & Wing area       \\
            b               & \SI{0.379}{m}    & Wing span       \\
            c               & \SI{2.91}{m}     & Wing mean chord \\
            AR              & 2.45             & Aspect ratio    \\
            e               & 0.92             & Oswald factor   \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular*}
        \captionof{table}{Geometric data}
    \end{minipage}

\end{strip} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

2.  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @alper (1) The exact width of the column is `0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep` (or `0.5\linewidth-0.5\columnsep` inside the strip environment) = 252.0pt = `0.48\linewidth`. I updated the code to make it more self explanatory.


(2) You can use `\begin{subfigure}... \end{subfigure}` (package `subcaption`) without additional packages.

Comment: Why `1.      \lipsum[1-2] (END)` continue from right column? Would it be possible to prevent it to split ?

Comment: @alper  The strip is after  `1. \lipsum[1-2] (END)` so it fill and balance this text into two columns first.

Comment: Can we force to put strip section bottom or top of the page like a figure?

Comment: @alper Move the strip after  `\section{Start}`